# how to return all values of a list vertically in python inside of a function without using print

Tags: python, list, loops

`prizes_remaining = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]`

I have this global list, I need a way of iterating through this list with a function and displaying it when the function is printed out later in the code.

```
    length = len(prizes_remaining)
    for i in range(length):
        return prizes_remaining[i]
```

I had something like this, but it only returns the first iteration of the list. I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```

Comment: Get rid of the `length` and `for` lines, then simply `return "\n".join(prizes_remaining)`. I would also read the answer posted by @Code-Apprentice for the best practice.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a generator?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Your current code is incomplete and has an error in it because you use `return` without a `def` for a function.

Comment: also explain in more detail about what you are trying to ultimately accomplish here. We can give you some pointers. "I need a way of iterating through this list with a function and displaying it when the function is printed out later in the code." doesn't make much sense because we don't "print a function". It sounds like you are trying to solve a homework problem or online coding challenge and you think you need to "return a vertical list", but your difficulty is more likely in how you are approaching the original problem, not what you are asking here.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are neither "vertical" nor "horizontal". They are just a sequence of elements. It doesn't make sense to say "return elements of a list vertically". The only thing that gives them a direction is when you print them out to view.

Keep in mind that it is best practice to keep logic that creates or manipulates a list separate from logic that displays the list. So you can return a list from a function and then `print()` it in another function.